# Revealing board in minesweeper

Tags: javafx

Im working on a minesweeper program and i would like a little help with revealing the whole board after the player has clicked on a bomb . Here is the code :

```
package narkalieutis;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Narkalieutis extends Application {

private int TILE_SIZE = 50;
private static final int W = 500;
private static final int H = 500;

private int X_TILES = W / TILE_SIZE;
private int Y_TILES = H / TILE_SIZE;
private final String[] gameType = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard", "Very Hard"};
private String difficulty;

@FXML
private Menu gameMenu;

private Tile[][] grid = new Tile[X_TILES][Y_TILES];
private Scene scene;

public MenuBar menu() {
    gameMenu = new Menu("Difficulty");
    for(String game : gameType){
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(game);
        menuItem.setUserData(game);
        menuItem.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            selectGame(event);
        });
        gameMenu.getItems().add(menuItem);
    }
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(gameMenu);
    return menuBar;
}

private void selectGame(ActionEvent event) {
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)event.getSource();
    difficulty = (String)menuItem.getUserData();
    switch (difficulty) {
        case "Easy":
            TILE_SIZE = 2*TILE_SIZE;
            break;
        case "Medium":
            TILE_SIZE = 100;
            break;
        case "Hard":
            TILE_SIZE = 50;
            break;
        case "Very Hard":
            TILE_SIZE = 40;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private Parent createContent() {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    Pane content = new Pane();
    content.setPrefSize(W, H);

    for (int y = 0; y < Y_TILES; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < X_TILES; x++) {
            Tile tile = new Tile(x, y, Math.random() < 0.2);

            grid[x][y] = tile;
            content.getChildren().add(tile);
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < Y_TILES; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < X_TILES; x++) {
            Tile tile = grid[x][y];

            if (tile.hasBomb)
                continue;

            long bombs = getNeighbors(tile).stream().filter(t ->      t.hasBomb).count();

            if (bombs > 0)
                tile.text.setText(String.valueOf(bombs));
        }
    }
    root.getChildren().addAll(menu(), content);

    return root;
}

private List<Tile> getNeighbors(Tile tile) {
    List<Tile> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] points = new int[] {
          -1, -1,
          -1, 0,
          -1, 1,
          0, -1,
          0, 1,
          1, -1,
          1, 0,
          1, 1
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        int dx = points[i];
        int dy = points[++i];

        int newX = tile.x + dx;
        int newY = tile.y + dy;

        if (newX >= 0 && newX < X_TILES
                && newY >= 0 && newY < Y_TILES) {
            neighbors.add(grid[newX][newY]);
        }
    }

    return neighbors;
}

private class Tile extends StackPane {
    private int x, y;
    private boolean hasBomb;
    private boolean isOpen = false;

    private Rectangle board = new Rectangle(TILE_SIZE - 2, TILE_SIZE - 2);
    private Text text = new Text();

  Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);

    public Tile(int x, int y, boolean hasBomb) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.hasBomb = hasBomb;

        board.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

        text.setFont(Font.font(18));
        text.setText(hasBomb ? "X" : "");
        text.setVisible(false);

        getChildren().addAll(board, text);

        setTranslateX(x * TILE_SIZE);
        setTranslateY(y * TILE_SIZE);

        setOnMouseClicked(e -> open());
    }

    public void open() {
        if (isOpen)
            return;

        if (hasBomb) {
    board.setVisible(true);
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                scene.setRoot(createContent());   
            }
           return;
        }

        isOpen = true;
        text.setVisible(true);
        board.setFill(null);

        if (text.getText().isEmpty()) {
            getNeighbors(this).forEach(Tile::open);
        }

        switch (text.getText()) {
            case "1":
                text.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case "2":
                text.setFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
                break;
            case "3":
                text.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case "4":
                text.setFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
                break;
            case "5":
                text.setFill(Color.MAROON);
                break;
            case "6":
                text.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
                break;
            case "7":
                text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                break;
            case "8":
                text.setFill(Color.GRAY);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    scene = new Scene(createContent());

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

Im trying to make it so that when the player loses the content of all the tiles is revealed .

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained exactly what problem you're having.  Based on what you've already achieved, it should be well within your ability to reveal all the tiles.

In createContent(), you already have nested for loops, one for x and one for y, that cover the entire board.  In this case they set the value of the tiles.

You simply need to do the same thing, but instead of set the tile value you simply reveal the tile, however you're doing that.  I imagine this would be replacing the grey tile with the icon representing what's inside it.